# Idris - use same interface instance

Tags: idris, monoids

I have a data structure

```
record IdentityPreservingMorphism domain codomain where
constructor MkMorphismOfMonoids
  func : domain -> codomain
  funcRespId : (Monoid domain, Monoid codomain) => func (Algebra.neutral) = Algebra.neutral
```

which just says that an `IdentityPreservingMorphism` is a morphism between monoids which needs to respect the identity.

I'm trying to prove that the identity morphisms is an `IdentityPreservingMorphism`

```
monoidIdentity : Monoid m => MorphismOfMonoids m m
monoidIdentity = MkMorphismOfMonoids
  id
  ?respId
```

The easy shot for `?respId` at `Refl` does not work because there are too many `Monoid` instances available. How can I tell the compiler that I would like to use only the instance coming from the `monoidIdentity` definition?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "proper" solution to this requires (1) writing a proof of a form `(m1 : Monoid m, m2 : Monoid m) => m1 = m2` and 2) being able to reify the two `Monoid` implementations from `funcRespId` to feed them into step 1. While the former can be simulated with a postulate/assert, it's the latter step that becomes problematic, which is probably related to https://github.com/idris-lang/Idris-dev/issues/4591.

A simpler workaround is to trivialize reification by storing implementations directly in the record:

```
record MorphismOfMonoids domain codomain where
  constructor MkMorphismOfMonoids
  func : domain -> codomain
  mon1 : Monoid domain
  mon2 : Monoid codomain
  funcRespId : func (Algebra.neutral @{mon1}) = Algebra.neutral @{mon2}

monoidIdentity : Monoid m => MorphismOfMonoids m m
monoidIdentity @{mon} = MkMorphismOfMonoids id mon mon Refl
```